# 405 method not allowed error when following below link

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I followed the below link to do a similar setup with `S3 static website + AWS API Gateway + AWS Lambda`.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/create-dynamic-contact-forms-for-s3-static-websites-using-aws-lambda-amazon-api-gateway-and-amazon-ses/

I am getting `405 Method` not allowed when I hit the submit button on the s3 form. I know `S3 static web hosting` doesn't allow **POST**. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Are you POST'ing to the API gateway URL?

Comment: yes, I am. 

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url : "https://8t******6i.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/sample_analyzer_test",
.
.

Comment: Then it means that your API gateway isn't setup quite right.  The inability to POST to S3 has nothing to do with the issue you're having as you are not POST'ing to S3, your POST'ing to API Gateway.  I'd use the browser tools to see the data you're sending and then, if that looks good, verify your API Gateway setup.

Comment: I had added headers to to method request instead of response on the API gateway. I worked after I corrected that. Thanks!